# How to get global javascript variables in imacros?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am using imacros to code in javascript and i cant seem to retrieve variables from the website pages javascript.

In the javascript for the page the variable is
window.vVals = (variable value here)

I need to get that using imacros, how would i do that? I have tried various things
window.vVals
vVals
window.content.vVals
But they all return undefined, its really frustrating now

Thanks

Edit:

```
<script>
window.vVals = {
'f': 'frm_sample',
'n': '57064044135dd',
'a': '57067289aa2c6'
};
</script>
```

The above is the code that is on the web page

Using IMacros i would like to retrieve the values of those variables (the values change everytime you refresh which is why i cant use any 1 value)

Comment: Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Please share the script for the better understanding of the problem

Comment: I have added the part of the script necessary

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the possible solutions:

```
iimPlayCode('SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(window\\\\.vVals = ((\\\\s|.)*?);)" EXTRACT=$2');
var vVals = JSON.parse(iimGetExtract().replace(/'/g, '"'));
```